# GridView visually not showing new data in BindingList

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm new to using MVVM with WPF and hit a roadblock. I have a `BindingList` that binds to the `ItemsSource` on a `GridView`. I added a button that uses a `RelayCommand` that pulls new data from the database and stores it in the `BindingList`. When debugging I can see the the new items in the `BindingList`, but visually it does not show in the grid. This has me stomped, please see my code blocks below:

This is the binding to the grid view:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAllShipments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShipment}"
```

This is the view model:

```
public class EntriesShipmentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public EntriesShipmentViewModel()
   {
      GetAllShipments();
      RefreshGridViewsCommand = new RelayCommand(GetAllShipments);
   }

   private BindingList<Shipment> _listOfAllShipments;
   private BindingList<Shipment> _listOfAssignedShipments;

   #region Private Properties

   private Shipment _selectedShipment;
   private string _manifestNumber;
   private string _carrier;
   private string _localShippingAgent;
   private string _voyageNumber;
   private string _shipmentKey;

   #endregion

   #region Public Properties

   public Shipment SelectedShipment
   {
      get => _selectedShipment;
      set
      {
         if (value == null)
            return;

         _selectedShipment = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(SelectedShipment.ToString());
         PopulateManifestInformation(SelectedShipment);
      }
   }

   public string ManifestNumber
   {
      get => _manifestNumber;
      set
      {
         _manifestNumber = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(ManifestNumber);
         OnPropertyRaised(nameof(ManifestNumber));
      }
   }

   public string Carrier
   {
      get => _carrier;
      set
      {
         _carrier = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(Carrier);
         OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Carrier));
      }
   }

   public string LocalShippingAgent
   {
      get => _localShippingAgent;
      set
      {
         _localShippingAgent = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(LocalShippingAgent);
         OnPropertyRaised(nameof(LocalShippingAgent));
      }
   }

   public string VoyageNumber
   {
      get => _voyageNumber;
      set
      {
         _voyageNumber = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(VoyageNumber);
         OnPropertyRaised(nameof(VoyageNumber));
      }
   }

   public string ShipmentKey
   {
      get => _shipmentKey;
      set
      {
         _shipmentKey = value;
         OnPropertyRaised(ShipmentKey);
         OnPropertyRaised(nameof(ShipmentKey));
      }
   }

   #endregion

   public ICommand RefreshGridViewsCommand { get; }

   private void GetAllShipments()
   {
      ListOfAllShipments = ShipmentViewModel.GetAllShipments();

      if (SelectedShipment != null)
      {
         SelectedShipment = null;
      }
   }

   public BindingList<Shipment> ListOfAllShipments
   {
      get => _listOfAllShipments;
      set
      {
         _listOfAllShipments = value;

      }
   }

   private void PopulateManifestInformation(Shipment shipment)
   {
      if (shipment == null)
         return;

      if (shipment.MasterManifest != null)
      {
         ManifestNumber = shipment.MasterManifest.Number;
         if (shipment.MasterManifest.IsMasterManifest && shipment.MasterManifest.Voyage != null)
         {
            Carrier = shipment.MasterManifest.Voyage.Carrier.Name;
            LocalShippingAgent = shipment.MasterManifest.LocalShippingAgent.Name;
            VoyageNumber = shipment.MasterManifest.Voyage.DisplayName;
         }

      }
      else if (shipment.SupplementaryManifest != null)
      {
         ManifestNumber = shipment.SupplementaryManifest.Number;
         if (shipment.SupplementaryManifest.IsMasterManifest && shipment.SupplementaryManifest.Voyage != null)
         {
            Carrier = shipment.SupplementaryManifest.Voyage.Carrier.Name;
            LocalShippingAgent = shipment.SupplementaryManifest.LocalShippingAgent.Name;
            VoyageNumber = shipment.SupplementaryManifest.Voyage.DisplayName;
         }

      }

      ShipmentKey = shipment.Id.ToString();
      }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Yeah, i tried it. Same thing happens. its updated in the collection but not visually in the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you create and assign an new collection to your `ListOfAllShipments` property:

```
ListOfAllShipments =  ShipmentViewModel.GetAllShipments();
```

However, you do not raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter, so the binding does not update.

```
public BindingList<Shipment> ListOfAllShipments
{
   get => _listOfAllShipments;
   set
   {
      _listOfAllShipments = value;
      OnPropertyRaised(nameof(ListOfAllShipments));
   }    
}
```

An alternative is to always **use the same collection**, but simply clear it using [`Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.clear?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_Clear) or [`ClearItems()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.clearitems?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_BindingList_1_ClearItems) in the `GetAllShipments` method and add the new items. These changes are automatically notified by the `BindingList`.

For the sake of completeness, some remarks about your code.

- You can remove `UpdateSourceTrigger` from the `ItemsSource` binding.
- The `OnPropertyRaised` calls get a **property name** as argument, so using `nameof` like this is ok:

  ```
  OnPropertyRaised(nameof(ShipmentKey));
  ```

  However, I do not think that the duplicate calls like below make sense, as you pass the **property value**. Therefore, you should be able to remove them without any difference.

  ```
  PropertyRaised(ShipmentKey);
  ```